# How can I configure category, subcategory and posts with slug in Django urls.py?

Tags: python, django

I need to configure Django urls like this:

```
/<slug_category>/
/<slug_category>/<slug_sub_category>/
/<slug_category>/<slug_post>/
```

I've tried this. The problem is that the `/<slug_category>/<slug_sub_category>/` and `/<slug_category>/<slug_post>/` give conflict.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)$', views.category),  
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug_subcategory>[\w-]+)/$', views.category), 

    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<post_slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.post),
]
```

Is it possible to do that? Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: They have the same regex structure, you could try using something like: `category/<category_slug>/post/<post_slug>`

Comment: Yes @Gotch. Thank you for your help! But unfortunately the site already exists (in Wordpress) and I want to keep the same structure of URLs.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use two different URLs because they have the same pattern (as has been pointed out in the comments). The solution is to use the same URL and to fetch the content accordingly. For example

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)$', views.category),  
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug_subcategory>[\w-]+)/$', views.cat_or_post), 

]
```

And then you have a function that will try to fetch a post and if that fails pass it to views.category. Something like this:

```
def cat_or_post(request,category_slug,slug_subcategory):
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug_subcategory)
        # put the rendering code here
     except Post.DoesnotExist:

        return category(request,category_slug,slug_subcategory)
```

Comment: Thank you @e4c5! I think this is the best option! But must ensure that slug_subcategory and slug_post are not equal.

Comment: Yes that is so, but generally word press auto generated post slugs are rather long where as category slugs are short. So it's unlikely to cause problems